# How to change react native application to a library to output aar file

Tags: react-native, aar

So basically, I want to change my existing react native application 0.71 to a react native library to output n aar file to integrate with native android application.

The error when i run "`./gradlew assembleDebug`" :

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.facebook.react:react-android:.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

what I've done:

1. change apply plugin: "`com.android.application`" to apply plugin: "`com.android.library`"
2. removed applicationId in default config